# Set Firefox >=3 to use a specific IP for all requests (NOT Proxy Server) | Used by Selenium|C#

Tags: firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

I have a Windows 7 computer that hat more than one IP-Address.
Now I want to set Firefox to always use a specific IP when using Profile A. And use a specific IP when using Profile B.

How can I archieve that?

I don't want to change or set a proxy server IP. My question aims just to the fact which IP firefox uses to send all requests from.

Background:

I am coding a C# selenium App and want to use two or more firefox profiles (and windows), and all have to use a different outgoing IP.

Comment: Based on what I've seen from other programs, and searching Google for threads on this topic, it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: I asked a former Firefox developer and he said it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox's uses the system's preferred network adapter. As such, this behaviour is not controlled by Firefox and cannot be modified inside Firefox.

You'll need to come up with another method. For the purpose of your Selenium tests, I'd suggest writing a debug behaviour which treats the IP as a debug-specific one when detects a certain user-agent.

You can change the user-agent on your second profile by going to about:config and changing:

**general.useragent.override**

and

**general.useragent.compatMode.firefox**